# MVC.Net Forms Authentication

Tags: asp.net-mvc, forms-authentication

I have used the forms authentication in my mvc.net project and it was working fine, the cookie is set in the browser with expiry date for a year but when I try to access the page after few hours its taking me to login page again not considering the active cookie.

This issue happens only when the code is deployed in the server, please do share your inputs on this.

In my c# code after the user is authenticated I am setting the cookie using the below line of code,

```
FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(username, true);
```

and in my web.config

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
   <forms name="_ac" loginUrl="/login" timeout="525600" defaultUrl="/" 
     slidingExpiration="false"></forms>
</authentication>
```

Its working in my local environment but after deploying in the development server its not working as expected, the session is getting expired in few minutes and forces the user to login.

Thanks,

Ram

Comment: Including your code helps others to give you high quality answers. Please check this [guideline](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) on how to ask a good question.

Comment: @bdongus I have added the code